# Can a suspended user award a bounty which they started before getting suspended?

Tags: support, bounty, account-suspension

My friend's account is suspended for a month in one of the Stack Exchange sites. He asked a bounty question and someone answered it. However, before he could award a bounty to the answer, his account got suspended.

Is there any option to award the bounty for that answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way that your friend could award a bounty when their account is suspended. However, if the bounty question has an answer with score >= 2, it will be automatically awarded half of the bounty after the end of grace period.

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) in Help Center:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for information, is there any way that moderators can award the bounty points to that answer ?

Comment: @spylh9999ggr No, moderators can't do that.

Comment: I feel this feature is really required.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100050/suspended-user-cannot-award-bounty, @spylh9999ggr. Not likely to happen.

Comment: @spylh9999ggr considering this is a SUPER edge case... I don't think "really required" is true here.

Comment: I feel this feature would really be waste of effort.